# solr 6.4.0 - Sorry, no dataimport-handler defined

Tags: solr

I have installed solr 6.4.0 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and want to use a configuration previously used on solr CLOUD 5.2.1

After creating a new core and linking the config files I can now see the core on the web interface and the files correctly under the core's administration interface.

The update link is greyed out and upon clicking on it it displays the error message:

> Sorry, no dataimport-handler defined!

The things I checked:

1. Solrconfig loads jar:

`<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="/usr/share/java/" regex="mysql-connector-java-.*\.jar" />`

Seems to work, as it displays an error message upon changing the filename. I therefore assume the mysql connector is loaded

2. Defined dataimport handler:

in solrconfig:

`<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">dataimport.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>`

3. Dataimporthandler itself

the file dataimport.xml is present and shows:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
            user="solr"
            password="secret" 
            convertType="true"
            batchSize="-1"
            encoding="UTF-8" />
 ...
```

The logfile inside the webadmin does not show any errors. I assume that logging is not configured to display this kind of error.

When I change the password inside dataimport.xml or the db name, nothing different happens. Same error message.

Any ideas on how to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem in previously i used 6.3.0

Comment: Does not look different to me except of the full path to the file?! https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Comment: The full path is not the problem. Tried it, same result.

Comment: Try doing [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10035?focusedCommentId=15838825&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-15838825). It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue is in the Admin UI, if you send the straight dataimport request you get the expected response.

There is a Bug for this on the Apache Jira site and a fix

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10035

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue. Changed following file:
solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/js/angular/controllers/dataimport.js
The string "QUERYHANDLER"  to "QUERY". Unfortunatlly still no import luck due to "unable to execute query" but that is another storry.

Comment: Make sure you delete your browser's cache (or load in chrome's incognito mode) after making that change or you'll tear you hair out trying to figure out why it didn't fix your problem (I speak from experience)

Answer (score 0):

i just downgraded to 6.3.0 and its working... seems like there are some changes for 6.4.0 with regards to dataimport handler

Comment: Doesn't a workaround help here?